# alias in a script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

In linux, if I put a command in a script that contains an alias, I see that it doesn't get expanded. How can I fix that? I am using bash.

Comment: can you show an example? What command? How are you aliasing it?

Comment: You should probably use functions instead of aliases. However GreenMatt's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424725/alias-in-a-script/3424805#3424805) is correct.

Answer (score 4):

According the the [TLDP page about aliases](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html), you need to use the line `shopt -s expand_aliases` in your code to expand aliases.  The example below produced the expected output, but without the shopt line it just printed "my_ls: command not found":

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias my_ls='ls -lrt'
echo "Trying my_ls"
my_ls
exit
```

Comment: interesting, the man page even implies the need for shopt, but for bash 3.2.39 it's turned on by default.

Comment: @mvds No it's not, out of the box. Probably your distro or etc had some unusual system-wide settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your shell aliases to be available in a script, you must manually include them. If they are defined in `~/.bashrc`, put a line

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

after the `#!/bin/sh` line in your script. This will execute the contents of .bashrc in the context of your script.

Comment: If the shebang identifies the script as a `sh` script, probably don't. Point being, the shebang should point to Bash, not `sh`, if you want to use Bash features. See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash). But also, this advice is slightly dubious because it requires your `.bashrc` to be idempotent. A better design, then, is to break out the code you want to share into a separate file, and source it from both `.bashrc` and your script.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling posix mode (such as by calling bash as `sh` or with the command `(set -o posix) 2>/dev/null && set -o posix` should do the trick.

Even then, be aware that aliases are expanded as they are parsed, and the ordering between parsing and execution is poorly defined. For example

```
alias foo=echo; foo bar
```

or

```
{
    alias foo=echo
    foo bar
}
```

will try to run `foo` as the alias is not defined at parse time yet. Also, some shells parse the whole input of an `eval` or `.` (source) before executing any of it.

So the only portable and reliable way to use aliases in scripts is to define them and then `eval` or `.` the code that uses them.